# Sharing a URL with a query string on Twitter

Tags: twitter, query-string, share, url-encoding

I'm trying to put a Twitter share link in an email.  Because this is in an email I can't rely on JavaScript, and have to use the "Build Your Own" Tweet button.

For example, sharing a link to Google:

```
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/share?url=http://www.google.com/>Tweet</a>
```

This works fine.  The problem I'm having is when the URL has a query string.

```
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/share?url=http://mysite.org/foo.htm?bar=123&baz=456">Tweet</a>
```

URLs with query strings confuse Twitter's URL shortening service, t.co.  I've tried URL encoding this in various ways and cannot get anything to work.  The closest I have gotten is by doing this.

```
<a href="http://www.twitter.com/share?url=http://mysite.org/foo.htm%3Fbar%3D123%26baz%3D456">Tweet</a>
```

Here I've encoded only the query string.  When I do this, t.co successfully shortens the URL, but upon following the shortened link, it takes you to the encoded URL.  I see `http://mysite.org/foo.htm%3Fbar%3D123%26baz%3D456` in the address bar, and get the following error in the browser

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /foo.htm?bar=123&baz=456 was not found on this server.

I'm at a loss as to how to solve this problem.

**Edit:**  Re: onteria_

I've tried encoding the entire URL.  When I do that no URL shows up in the Tweet.

Comment: You need to url encode the ENTIRE URL. That includes everything from the `http://` down

Answer (score 137, accepted):

This can be solved by using `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet` instead of `http://www.twitter.com/share`.  Using the `intent/tweet` function, you simply URL encode your entire URL and it works like a charm.

https://dev.twitter.com/web/intents

Comment: Plume and Tweetcaster don't handle this format (they just show the profile for intent or share, depending on the URL). Tweetdeck doesn't seem to handle twitter.com URLs at all.

Comment: Also see this link - http://blog.socialsourcecommons.org/2011/03/creating-share-this-on-facebooktwitter-links/

Comment: `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text={text_to_share}` works perfectly on all platforms. Been searching high and low for this.. Thanks!

Answer (score 238):

This will Work For You

```
http://twitter.com/share?text=text goes here&url=http://url goes here&hashtags=hashtag1,hashtag2,hashtag3
```

Here is a Live Example About it

---

[http://twitter.com/share?text=Im Sharing on Twitter&url=https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943186/youssef-subehi&hashtags=stackoverflow,example,youssefusf](http://twitter.com/share?text=Im%20Sharing%20on%20Twitter&url=https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943186/youssef-subehi&hashtags=stackoverflow,example,youssefusf)

Comment: Would have been a good answer if it … you know … answered the original question.

Comment: This sharing link structure is not working anymore. Use https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text={your text} instead

Answer (score 35):

Use tweet web intent, this is the simple link:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=<?=urlencode($url)?>
```

more variables at https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent

Answer (score 22):

It's working for me:

```html
<div class="links">
    <ul>
    <li class="social-share facebook">Share on Facebook</li>
    <li class="social-share twitter">Share on Twitter</li>
    <li class="social-share linkedin">Share on LinkedIn</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And in js file add this:

```js
setShareLinks();

    function socialWindow(url) {
    var left = (screen.width -570) / 2;
    var top = (screen.height -570) / 2;
    var params = "menubar=no,toolbar=no,status=no,width=570,height=570,top=" + top + ",left=" + left;  window.open(url,"NewWindow",params);}

function setShareLinks() {
    var pageUrl = encodeURIComponent(document.URL);
    var tweet = encodeURIComponent($("meta[property='og:description']").attr("content"));

$(".social-share.facebook").on("click", function() { url="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=" + pageUrl;
socialWindow(url);
});

$(".social-share.twitter").on("click", function() {
url = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=" + pageUrl + "&text=" + tweet;
socialWindow(url);
});

$(".social-share.linkedin").on("click", function() {
    url = "https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=" + pageUrl;
socialWindow(url);
})
}
```

Hope this will work well.

Comment: Nice i love this

Comment: Here is the same code, but nicely formatted: https://codepen.io/emohamed/pen/jOzPxgv

Answer (score 14):

You can use these functions:

```
 function shareOnFB(){
       var url = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://yoururl.com&t=your message";
       window.open(url, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');
       return false;
  }


function shareOntwitter(){
    var url = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=URL_HERE&via=getboldify&text=yourtext';
    TwitterWindow = window.open(url, 'TwitterWindow',width=600,height=300);
    return false;
 }


function shareOnGoogle(){
     var url = "https://plus.google.com/share?url=https://yoururl.com";
     window.open(url, '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=350,width=480');
     return false;
}


<a onClick="shareOnFB()"> Facebook </a>
<a onClick="shareOntwitter()"> Twitter </a>
<a onClick="shareOnGoogle()"> Google </a>
```

Comment: A solution that doesn't rely on javascript would just build these links (in `var url = ...`) when generating the email.

Answer (score 9):

Doesn't get simpler than this:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=optional%20promo%20text%20http://example.com/foo.htm?bar=123&baz=456" target="_blank">Tweet</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

You must to change & to %26 in query string from your url

Look at this: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/8616

Answer (score 5):

I reference all the methods.

Encode the query twice is the fast solution.

```
const query = a=123&b=456;
const url = `https://example.com/test?${encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(query),)}`;


const twitterSharingURL=`https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?&url=${url}`
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't necessarily need to use intent, it you encode your URL it will work with twitter share as well.

Answer (score 2):

As @onteria_ mentioned, you need to encode the entire parameter. For anyone else facing the same issue, you can use the following bookmarklet to generate the properly encoded url. Copy paste it into your browser's address bar to create the **twitter share url**. Make sure that the `javascript:` prefix is there when you copy it into address bar, Google Chrome removes it when copying.

```
javascript:(function(){var url=prompt("Enter the url to share");if(url)prompt("Share the following url - ","http://www.twitter.com/share?url="+encodeURIComponent(url))})();
```

Source on JS Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/2frkV/

Answer (score 2):

If you add it manual on html site, just replace:

```
&
```

With

```
&amp;
```

Standard html code for &

Comment: A full doc for building shared links using js https://css-tricks.com/simple-social-sharing-links/

Answer (score 1):

Twitter now lets you send the URL through a data attribute. This works great for me:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en" data-text="check out link b" data-url="http://www.lyricvideos.org/tracks?videoURL=SX05JZ4FisE">Tweet</a>
```

Comment: Has anyone tested to see if this relies on javascript from the twitter API to pull the url from the attribute and then redirect the browser to the right URL?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Twitter Intent resource https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/web-intent

Comment: including a key snippet to answering the question would help