# Reply a tweet using intents, through Android native application

Tags: android, twitter

I am developing an app in which I first list tweets from an account (using HttpClient and so, I'd rather not use twitter4j).

When the user click on a tweet from the list all the content is shown, and I'd like to have a button to be able to reply to that tweet.

I've succesfully managed to let the user send a tweet through the native Twitter app. However, it doesn't associate that response to the original tweet, it is presented just as a new tweet.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
String tweetUrl = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=EXAMPLE TEST&url=https://www.google.com&in_reply_to_status_id=STATUS ID";
Uri uri = Uri.parse(tweetUrl);
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri));
```

If I put the same url in a web browser, it handles the reply correctly, so I guess this is a problem of the native app not getting all the parameters correctly.

Does anybody know how this could be solved? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might help you :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208363/sharing-a-url-with-a-query-string-on-twitter

Comment: I'm afraid not. It works in a web browser, but not in android...
For example, this url (https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=TWEET_NUMBER) works fine in a web browser, it prompts to reply to that specific tweet, whereas in Android it just opens a window to post a tweet, but without the @user or indicating that it is a reply

Comment: @AliImran The link that you mentioned is not specific to the question asked above.

Comment: This does not work for me either - the twitter app is lagging behind their public api as it cannot correctly interpret the web intents - i dont understand why not as I imagine twitter may be able to afford and android developer or two!