# Direct tweet reply URL link? URL Query String for Twitter Tweet Reply?

Tags: url, twitter

How do I generate an URL that will automatically open the "tweet your reply" compose window?

- Example Tweet: https://twitter.com/CanadiensMTL/status/1490808598242512898
- What I thought would work (but doesn't): https://twitter.com/compose/tweet/1490808598242512898

Instead of actually making a person click the reply button, it'll just auto-open the compose box for a specific tweet.

Normally, I can just right click copy link, but when I'm on twitter, there is no copy link option when I right click because it's a `<button>` and not an `<a>` I guess... and when I left click the speech bubble reply icon the url bar says `https://twitter.com/compose/tweet` but I was hoping to specifically  find a "compose tweet reply" link to generate. In a perfect world I thought I would just be able to visit `https://twitter.com/compose/tweet/1490808598242512898` but that doesn't work.

I was able to scrape some "specific" urls but nothing that "replies". Any ideas?

- https://twitter.com/GameSpot/status/1490844073187442692
- https://twitter.com/GameSpot/status/1490844073187442692/likes
- https://twitter.com/GameSpot/status/1490844073187442692/retweets
- https://twitter.com/GameSpot/status/1490844073187442692/retweets/with_comments

[image: no copy link option]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find answer [thanks to another post I found on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767663/reply-a-tweet-using-intents-through-android-native-application?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment18954252_13767663) stackoverflow:

- `https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?in_reply_to=TWEET_NUMBER`

and just replace / swap TWEET_NUMBER

Comment: It seems from https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/tweet-button/overview that you have to include the Twitter for Websites JavaScript library to get this to work these days.