# Twitter button fails to put the current URL in the tweet

Tags: twitter

I tried to use the javascript method from  [Twitter's docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button) and the button maker from [here](https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#tweet)

. However, both buttons fail to put the current URL in the tweet. Any solution to this?

I tried to follow the answer from

- [Sharing a URL with a query string on Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208363/sharing-a-url-with-a-query-string-on-twitter)

on using intent/tweet instead of share, but it still does not put current URL to the tweet. Any solution?

The URLs would be something like

```
localhost:11080/result?day=monday&start=0900&end=1430&faculty=Computer+Science.
```

Comment: It wasn't with links because my reputation is not enough to put more than two links, or so the site said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/intent/tweet/` page silently removes non-publically visible URLs (such as `localhost`).  Just found this out after a few hours of puzzling trial and error.

Comment: Another quirk I discovered during the same testing session - if the host part of your URL is an IP address, it won't be shortened and auto-linked to a t.co address.