# social sharing links popup not showing correct URL on share page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

https://jsfiddle.net/6yrr82ph/

i am trying to share this link
`http://www.domain.com/list.php?id=10&category=food`

but on share page i am just getting

`http://www.domain.com/list.php?id=10` this link on the share page.

i have a trouble form getting 2nd variable `category`.

i don't know what wrong is going on. please fix this code

```
<div class="list text-center" style="margin: 10px;">  

         <a class="item" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://www.domain.com/list.php?id=10&category=food', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">    
           facebook share  <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>            </a><br><br>  
       <a class="item" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://twitter.com/share?text=title of blog&url=http://www.domain.com/list.php?id=70&category=food', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">                <i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i>      twitter share     
       </a> 


     </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sharing a URL with a query string on Twitter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208363/sharing-a-url-with-a-query-string-on-twitter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode your url with `urlencode`.

Try this :

```
<a class="item" href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode("http://www.domain.com/list.php?id=10&category=food");?>', '_system', 'location=yes'); return false;">
```

Answer (score 0):

also try this

```
 <script>
           url='http://www.domain.com/list.php?id=70&category=food';
          url= encodeURIComponent(url);
        </script>
```

put this encoded url to your code

```
window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+url, '_system', 'location=yes')
```