# Programmatically open the dialog box to Share to Twitter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter, share

I'm trying to implement twitter share in my React app. Judging by Twitter's SDK documentation, it seems like they really only show you how to include a twitter button (styled by them) which, when clicked, opens a dialog box to share your current url to twitter. The code looks something like this:

```
<a
className="twitter-share-button"
href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet"
>
 Tweet
</a>

<script>
 window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
   t = window.twttr || {};
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
 js = d.createElement(s);
 js.id = id;
 js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

 t._e = [];
 t.ready = function(f) {
   t._e.push(f);
 };

 return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"))
</script>
```

I need to do 3 things:

1. Dictate the url I would like to be sharing
2. Customize the twitter share button to look completely different
3. Occasionally in my program, I need to open the twitter share dialog box without clicking any button at all

Can anyone offer any help or point me in the right direction, because I've had a very hard time finding any helpful resources. Thanks

Comment: Look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208363/sharing-a-url-with-a-query-string-on-twitter

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks